# CircleCi let only team-leaders team from github to approve a job

Tags: circleci, circleci-2.0, circleci-workflows

I'm trying to add an approval job and I want only users from "team-leaders" groups at GitHub can click the approve.

what I've done so far:

I created a GitHub team - "team-leaders" and added only me to the group.

add this step to the workflow:

```
    approval:
        jobs:
           - approval:
               type: approval
```

when I'm uploading a new commit it does create an approval job that holds, but every user can accept this job and not only the users from the team leaders.

can I make that only the team leaders can approve my job?

Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You **can't** restrict the approval action; as you found out, any user who has `write` access to the repo/project can perform this action.

What  you **can** do though, is apply a restricted context to all the
downstream jobs. You can find an example in the CircleCI documentation > https://circleci.com/docs/contexts/#approve-jobs-that-use-restricted-contexts.